# How can I read a csv persian file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, persian

I am trying to read a non-English `.csv` file in python but I am facing an encoding error. Can you please help me to solve this problem?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 53587: invalid start byte
```

Code used:

```
import pandas as pd 

with open('1.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    train = f.read().splitlines() 
    print(train)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample?

Comment: impossible to answer without a sample of the file in question

Comment: What python version are you using? What pandas method are you using to read the file? If opening the file on your own, what mode do you use before passing the handle to pandas?

Comment: I'd expect that your encoding is not UTF-8. Find the real encoding and add it as an input parameter

Comment: This is a real challenge. There are multiple ways to encode a file and sometimes files are just corrupted. You could play around with various codecs that you think might work for the text but that is a hit-and-miss kind of thing. Does most of the string decode its non-ascii text properly? In that case it could be corruption.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? Python 3's file `open()` has an optional parameter called `encoding` using which you could read a `UTF-8` encoded file. Also could you please share the partial contents of the file you're trying to read. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Actually, I use Python 3 and my code is like this:
import pandas as pd
with open('1.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    train = f.read().splitlines()
    print(train)

Comment: Could you share a bit more about how the file is created? Also, the bit about how you really read it should be in the question itself.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : I just use a simple CSV file with different columns such as numbers and Persian text. When I open it in my python editor (Pycharm), I just see my data like this: 9820000355,????.??? 12???? ?? ???? ????? .
The error says the file is loaded in wrong encoding. So, I change it multiple times in the setting but nothing works on it.

Comment: You're missing the point of my question. Someone is creating the "simple csv". That program is setting the encoding. Instead of stabbing blindly in the dark and wasting time, track down that information. This stuff can be very complicated sometimes, but it's not magic.

Comment: Could you give us a copy of the CSV file? Use a service such as pastebin and post a link to it.

Comment: I found out the CSV file had a problem. after exporting again it works fine. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i think your file encoding is inappropriate. I used below code for many Persian csv files and it works!

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: This is rather missing the point. You have to *know* the encoding.

Comment: Most of the time encoding is "Arabic(Windows-1256)"

Comment: "Most of the time" in your scenario maybe, but there is no way generally to predict that. Again, you have to know the encoding of the data before you can process it usefully.

Comment: I agree with you. I mean in Persian most of the time Arabic is True encoding.